# how to bind json for extjs grid

Tags: extjs

I have a simple data in `mysql` and want to populate that data in a ExtJS grid

> My code

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var proxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'connectextjs.php'
    });

    var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader([{
        name: 'Employee_ID',
        mapping: 'Employee_ID'
    }, {
        name: 'Department_ID'
    }, {
        name: 'Name'
    }, {
        name: 'Email'
    }])

    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        proxy: proxy,
        reader: reader
    });

    store.load();


    // create the grid
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
        columns: [{
            header: "Employee_ID",
            width: 90,
            dataIndex: 'Employee_ID',
            sortable: true
        }, {
            header: "Department_ID",
            width: 90,
            dataIndex: 'Department_ID',
            sortable: true
        }, {
            header: "Name",
            width: 90,
            dataIndex: 'Name',
            sortable: true
        }, {
            header: "Email",
            width: 200,
            dataIndex: 'Email',
            sortable: true
        }],
        renderTo: 'example-grid',
        width: 540,
        height: 200
    });

});
```

My problem is I can't load the data on the grid. Please help me I am new to ExtJS.

Comment: What does `connectextjs.php` return?

Answer (score 0):

connectextjs.php should return the json formated data with Employee_ID,Deaprtment_ID ,Name and Email init. Namming Convention should be followed strictly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data of the grid by using this method.

1. First, assign an id to your grid, like this:

   ```
   itemId : 'myGrid';
   ```
2. Get the JSON loaded from your JSON call, like this:

   ```
   Ext.Ajax.request({
   url : 'connectextjs.php',

   params : {

   yourParam : 'yourParameters'

   },

   // --> success simply means your action has no errors

   success : function (conn, response, options, eOpts){

     var jsonResults = Ext.JSON.decode(conn.responseText);


     // --> Now that you have your JsonResults Its time to set it to your grid
     me.getView().down('#myGrid').setStore(jsonResults);

   }

   });
   ```